# AWS SES not recieving email

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am sending email using AWS SES service.

I am using sendTemplatedEmail and sendBulkTemplatedEmail functions for sending an email via API.

I am getting success message but unable to receive an email in my inbox. I have tried using different domains

Response after using above functions:

```
info: { ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: '4f694a7d-3bc0-11e8-a122-797ebd5d1c30' },
  MessageId: '01000162a91e9d85-8fc9e769-e6e4-43e0-8a26-08ef241ed6c1-000009' }
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Doesn't the mail go into spams/junk?

Comment: I had checked everywhere  doesn't receive email anywhere

Comment: Have you verified the domain you send the mail from? I am referring to the Domains section in the SES Home. You should see your domain verified there.

Comment: I am sending email from the verified email. I have also increased my sending limit.

Comment: @Mahdi: I send email from my postman i am creating API for sending email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer to my question.

I am sending one of the replacement data as 'undefined' which act as a value for AWS SES 
template that why it is returning me success response.

But, that undefined value can't be parsed by any email service provider so that is the reason I am unable to receive it in my inbox